# URLConnection doesn't work with public FTP servers in Android

Tags: java, android, url, ftp, urlconnection

**My issue**: my android device is unable to connect to a public FTP server using `URLConnection`. However, when the device tried to connect to a public FTP server (`anonymous` for username and no password), it cannot retrieve the InputStream from `urlConnection.getInputStream();`.

I do not use `FTPClient` from `Apache Commons` library because the speed is quite limited... A related question regarding that limited speed with FTPClient is here 
[FTPClient's download is slower than URLConnection's download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768359/ftpclients-download-is-slower-than-urlconnections-download). 
Whatever I tried with the urlString:

```
urlString = protocol+"://" + username+"@" +address+":"+port + filepath + file;
// ftp://anonymous@speedtest.tele2.net:21/100GB.zip
urlString = protocol+"://" + username+":" + password + "@" +address+":"+port + filepath + file;
// ftp://anonymous:@speedtest.tele2.net:21/100GB.zip
urlString = protocol+"://" + username+":" + "password" + "@" +address+":"+port + filepath + file;
// ftp://anonymous:password@speedtest.tele2.net:21/100GB.zip
urlString = protocol+"://" + address+":"+port + filepath + file;
// ftp://speedtest.tele2.net:21/100GB.zip
```

`downloadAndBroadcastURL:after getinputStream` is never got logged with open FTP servers. I also tried with these two public FTP servers:

```
ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/100GB.zip
ftp://ftp.funet.fi/dev/1GBnull
```

But it doesn't connect as well.

**My code:**

```
private void downloadAndBroadcastURL() {
    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        String urlString;
        if (username.equals("anonymous")){
            urlString = protocol+"://" + username+"@" +address+":"+port + filepath + file;
        } else {
            urlString = protocol+"://" + username+":" + password + "@" +address+":"+port + filepath + file;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcastURL: "+ urlString);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcastURL:after connect ");
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcastURL:after getinputStream");

        /*******************************
          The rest is about handling the input stream, the download...
         *****************************/

        long difference;
        byte data[] = new byte[4094];
        int count;
        while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1 && download) {
            downloadCount += count;
            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            difference = stopTime - beginTime;
            if (difference > 1000 && download) {
                currentSpeed = downloadCount / (difference / 1000L); //for precision, because difference can be more than 1000 sometimes
                averageSpeed = (averageSpeed + currentSpeed) / 2;
                Log.d(TAG, "Speed: " + downloadCount + " bytes/s. " + (downloadCount / 1024) + "kB/s " + (downloadCount / 128) + "kbit/s " + (downloadCount / 1048576) + "Mb/s " + ((downloadCount) / (1024 * 128)) + "Mpbs" + (downloadCount / 131072) + "Mbit/s difference:" + difference + "ms");
                if (download) {
                    broadcastSpeed();
                }
                downloadCount = 0; //Resetoidaan määrä
                beginTime = stopTime;
            }
            if (!download) {
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcast: download stops");
                clearInputStream();
            }
        }
        clearInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "FAIL " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcastURL: ");
        clearInputStream();
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadAndBroadcast: finally");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `protocol+"://"` So we would know which protocol you use?

Comment: @greenapps The protocol is `ftp`

Comment: Use an FTP client instead.

Comment: @greenapps "I do not use FTPClient from Apache Commons library because the speed is quite limited..." another question regarding this problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768359/ftpclients-download-is-slower-than-urlconnections-download